# Possible to pass anonymous function or reference to function to executeScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to pass an anonymous function to the chrome API executeScript call? Currently I have the following code:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: "document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));"})
```

Is there a way to pass the code I want executed as a function reference, rather than a string? I know of the file option, but I'd prefer to just pass a reference to a function already provided in bg.js. I don't like the string because I lose syntax highlighting/formatting in my editor, amongst other reasons.

Answer (score 2):

You can represent your function as a string:

```
var f = function(){ /* do stuff */ }
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: "("+f.toString()+")();"});
```

Be careful, the function still needs to be self-contained (not use any non-local variables), as it will be executed in a different context.

Comment: This gotta be kidding man.. Surely there's a real solution to this problem? What about passing objects?

Comment: @Pacerier It probably depends on what your problem, as opposed to the original question, is. If it's sufficiently different, make a new question.