# Chrome Extension -> ExecuteScript: function call doesn' work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

He is my **manifest.json**:

```
{
  "name": "Page Redder",
  "description": "Make the current page red",
  "version": "2.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab","*://*/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon" : "icon.png",
    "default_title": "Make this page red"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Here is **background.js** that works (the page becomes red):

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

   chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code:'document.body.style.backgroundColor="red";'} );


});
```

If I change **background.js** in the following way, it fails to work:

```
function changeColor() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor="red";

}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

   chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code:';'}, function() {
      changeColor();
   });

});
```

**Chrome build**: 38.0.2125.111

**The question:** what am I doing wrong here? Why calling a function in executeScript doesn't work?

Thanks,
Racoon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling a function *in* `executeScript`.

You are calling the function in its callback, that runs in the original (background) page. It's a function describing "what to do when `executeScript` finishes", not the code to run.

The code that actually runs in the page you're injecting code to is ";" (which obviously does nothing).

You *can* [run a function defined in your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631452/possible-to-pass-anonymous-function-or-reference-to-function-to-executescript/25631544#25631544) with `executeScript` by properly converting it into a string. But note that it will not have any access to variables defined outside the function.

---

I think what you're *trying* to do is to make the code accept a parameter (color). Instead of crafting custom code each time, you should consider using [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to pass a command.

Example: add a file `content.js` with the following:

```
// Include guard: only execute once
if (!injected) {
  injected = true;
  init();
}

function init() {
  // Get ready to receive a command
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(message.action == "colorBackground") {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = message.color;
    }
  });
}
```

And in your background, you can do this:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content.js"}, function() {
  // File executed, it's ready for the message
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(null, { action: "backgroundColor", color: "green" });
}
```

Comment: Xan, thanks for the valuable answer! No, I don't try to accept a parameter. It was the simplest example with using a function I could imagein. Actually, I want to do some operations on the form fields, but don't want to present code as one string. So I wanted to place code in the function and run it from executeScript. Is it possible without Messaging? Thanks, Racoon.

Comment: It is possible, see [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631452/possible-to-pass-anonymous-function-or-reference-to-function-to-executescript/25631544#25631544). But this is not a very good architecture.

Comment: If you want to run some longer code repeatedly, consider putting it in a js file and executing `{file: "filename.js"}`.